# It looks unsized (messy) while refreshing the page at each time

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, page-refresh

I use Vue  Framework for my webpage and I got an error that is unsized divs (especially Navbar) while refreshing the page. This problem doesn't occur on my homepage (index.vue). It only occurs on `hireABikePage`. Even if I delete all the codes (including template, script and style) from this page and only `Navbar` exists, I can still see the same problem but a bit quick.

Here is my `hireABikePage` file:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row d-flex  align-items-center">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <div class="card d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mb-5">
                        <img class="img-fluid my-4 " src="~assets/images/cycle.jpg" alt="cycle"/>
                        <div class="item-details w-100">
                            <h3 class="item-title">Ridley Helium X Ultegra</h3>
                            <p class="item-prefix">PER</p>
                            <p class="item-price">€30</p>
                            <p class="item-prefix">DAY</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <div class="card d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mb-5">
                        <img class="img-fluid my-4 " src="~assets/images/cycle2.jpg" alt="cycle"/>
                        <div class="item-details w-100">
                            <h3 class="item-title">Cube e-bike Acid Hybrid ONE 400</h3>
                            <p class="item-prefix">PER</p>
                            <p class="item-price">€25</p>
                            <p class="item-prefix">DAY</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <div class="card d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mb-5">
                        <img class="img-fluid my-4 " src="~assets/images/cycle3.jpg" alt="cycle"/>
                        <div class="item-details w-100">
                            <h3 class="item-title">Ridley Fenix SL Disc 105</h3>
                            <p class="item-prefix">PER</p>
                            <p class="item-price">€28</p>
                            <p class="item-prefix">DAY</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <div class="card d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mb-5">
                        <img class="img-fluid my-4 " src="~assets/images/cycle3.jpg" alt="cycle"/>
                        <div class="item-details w-100">
                            <h3 class="item-title">Ridley lala model x</h3>
                            <p class="item-prefix">PER</p>
                            <p class="item-price">€35</p>
                            <p class="item-prefix">DAY</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'hireABikePage'
}
</script>

<style>
    .card{
        width: 30rem !important;
        height: auto !important;
    }
    .card img{   
        max-width: 85%;
        height: 25rem;
        width: 25rem;
    }
    .item-details{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .item-title{
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        margin-right: 2rem;
        margin-left: 2rem;
    }
    .item-price{
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
        background-color: var(--color-dark-blue);
        font-size: 5rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-right: 2rem;
        padding-left: 2rem;
        border-radius: 1.5rem 1.5rem 1.5rem 1.5rem;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .item-prefix{
        display: inline-block;
        color: orange;
        font-size: 2rem;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
</style>
```

This is also a screenshot for [how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo7jj.png)
Original [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qjmB.png)

I checked class names whether they are same with other components' class names or not but I didn't see any same class. I am trying to solve this issue for a day, couldn't solve it yet. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Assuming the navbar uses `.card` classname, your hireABike page is overriding the styling because  your `<style>` tag isn't [scoped](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html). It doesn't explain all the CSS differences but you can debug the rest by inspecting the DOM and seeing what CSS is applied to the navbar on your index page vs hireABike. The inspector will tell you what stylesheet is applying the CSS so you should be able to track down the same CSS in your code, which will hopefully let you figure out the how/where/why a style is being applied on one page but not the other.

Comment: Actually, their class names are different from each other. Navbar doesn't have a class like `.card`. I checked all my components and pages but class names are not same. I also didn't use `scoped` for `<style>` tag because it is removed. Can I do something else for my problem if you know? Resizing occurs during loading when refreshed the page. @yoduh

Comment: I found that! I had to add `@import "~assets/css/global.css";` within `<style>`. I couldn't recognize it. It was so easy. Thanks for your help!